# Library is missing when run 'shutter'

Tags: perl, shutter

I am trying to install [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). I have `Linux Mint 17.3` and install it as:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

But when I run it after installation I get error:

```
Can't locate Shutter/App/SimpleDialogs.pm in @INC
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

This programm put its library into `/usr/share/perl5/`. So to use it you should setup `PERL5LIB` env variable to that folder. In my `.bashrc` I do:

```
export PERL5LIB="/usr/share/perl5/:${PERL5LIB}"
```

Comment: This should not be necessary `/usr/share/perl5` should already be one of the lib search directories compiled into the Perl interpreter.  You can confirm this with `perl -V`. It sounds more like there has been an error during the packaging of the application.

Comment: @GrantMcLean In `perlbrew` environment there is no `/usr/share/perl5` location, for example

Comment: Sure, but a Perl application installed via `apt-get` would usually use the system perl which was also installed via `apt-get`. I would have thought the main script for shutter would start with `#!/usr/bin/perl` to invoke the system Perl and the system Perl has a compiled-in search path that includes /usr/share/perl5. The fact that you might also have another Perl installed via perlbrew shouldn't affect any of that.